# Update chart.js in laravel from controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, chart.js

I am attempting to update my chart.JS in my view when a new date is selected from the date picker. I think I got pretty close.

The date goes from my datepicker through to my controller via AJAX post:

```
<div class="col py-3">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Water Data</h1>
                @csrf
                <input type="text" name="daterange"/> Enter date range for water data
                
                <script>
                $(function() {
                  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    opens: 'left'
                  }, function(start, end, label) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "/basicecho",
                        method: "POST",
                        data:{startdate: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), endate: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')},
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            
                            $('#dateSelected').text(data);
                            
                        },  
                    });
                    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                    dd(data);
                    return false;
```

My controller responds with this function:

```
function getDate(Request $request){
        $date = $request->all();
        $d2=array_values($date);
        $start = $d2[0];
        $end = $d2[1];
        
        $this->update($start,$end);
        return;
     }
```

Which in turn, calls the SQL query:

```
 public function update($a,$b)
    {
         
         if ($a==1){
            $a= date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-18 days"));
            $b=date('Y-m-d');
        }
        $string="SELECT top ";
        $s2= " 2 * FROM [JDDProduction].[jd2exp].[CaveWaterTotal]";
        $s3= $string.$s2;
        //dd($key2);
        $usage = DB::table('jd2exp.CaveWaterTotal')
             -> select('JD1Cave','JD2Cave_calc')
             ->whereBetween("Date",[$a,$b])
             ->get();
           
       $output=[];      
       $values = ($usage->first());
       $i =0;
       foreach ($values as $entry){
            $output[$i]=($entry);
            $i+=1;
       }
       $data = (array_values($output));
       $labels = [
         'JD1Cave','JD2Cave_calc'
       ];
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

The data is correct and present in the $data tag at the end of the controller. However, I can't seem to get it back into the View.

I think I have messed up how the flow the controller/view should work. I have ->View is generated with current date -> Date picker posts new dats to controller -> Controller generates response -> ????

The chart is generated in the View as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  var Data = @json($data)

  const data = {
  labels: [
    'JD1Cave','JD2Cave_calc'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: '',
    data: Data,
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
    
    ],
    hoverOffset: 4
  }]
    };
    const centerText = {
        id:'centerText',
        afterDatasetDraw(chart,args,pluginOptions){
            const {ctx}=chart;
            ctx.textAlign = 'center'
            console.log(Data);
            var result = Data.map(function (x) { 
                return parseFloat(x, 10); 
            }); 
            const atext = 'Total Gallons:'
            const text =result.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0);
            //const text = atext.conacat(btext)
            console.log(text);
            //.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            ctx.font = 'bold 30px san-serif';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(54,162,235,1)';
            const textWidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
            const x = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x
            const y = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].y
            
           
            //ctx.fillStyle = 'rbga(54,162,235,1)';
            ctx.fillText(atext,x,y-20);
            ctx.font = 'bold 24px san-serif';
            ctx.fillText(text,x,y);
           
        
    }
}
   const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options:{
    plugins:{
        legend:{
            position:'right'
        }
    }
  },
  plugins:[centerText]
};
```

I attempted to use an ajax get and it was a failure:

```
var updateChart = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/basicecho'
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            myChart.data.datasets[0].data=data.data;
            myChart.update();
        }
    });
    
}
    updateChart();
    setInterval(() => {
        updateChart();
    },1000);
```

Can someone help me sort out the order of things so I can update my chart appropriately?

aynber Pointed it out that I wasn't returning my data. I have fixed it, and can now see the data coming into the console of the running app. I'm not sure how to get the chart to update with it though.

getDate now returns the Json data response:

```
    function getDate(Request $request){
    $date = $request->all();
    $d2=array_values($date);
    $start = $d2[0];
    $end = $d2[1];
    
    $data = $this->update($start,$end);
    return response()->json($data);
 }
```

Comment: Your getDate controller function is returning null instead of returning the result of the update function.

Comment: Oh my gosh. You are correct. I have fixed that, and I now see the updated data coming into the consol. But I'm not sure how to get it to update the chart.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with charts.js, but you may need to just redraw the chart